# How to animate images onslide of ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I animate objects on swipe of fragments in Viewpager? I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this effect by attaching OnPageChangeListener on your viewPager.

```
@Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // use positionOffset and position to zoom in-out of your image
            //For ex you have to zoom images on fragment on 1st index.
           // zoom the images in when you get position = 0 and set zoom level according to positionOffsetPixels
        }
```

I hope you will get ahead with answer. If you have any doubt ask away. Giving you a small example for the above explanation:

```
 @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            if (position==0){
                fragment1.setZoomImage(positionOffset);
            }
        }
```

Method in fragment1:

```
public void setZoomImage(float zoom){
    if (zoomImage!=null){
        zoomImage.setPadding((int)(padding-(zoom*padding)),(int)(padding-(zoom*padding)),(int)(padding-(zoom*padding)),(int)(padding-(zoom*padding)));
    //padding is the max padding you want for the image.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something called the MotionLayout

You will need to create a MotionScene file can contain all that is needed for specifying the animation.

[image: This is I guess something for what you are looking for]

You can find a detailed explanation here: https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-iii-47cd64d51a5

What you want is motionlayout with viewpager

Best of luck